# How do I scrape data from a javascript-website using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a few months of programming experience with Python and would like to undertake a larger project for academic purposes, where I collect and analyze injury histories of football players.

The data source is a website that tracks such data based on media reports. Here's an example of Kylian Mbappe: https://www.transfermarkt.com/kylian-mbappe/verletzungen/spieler/342229

Using a Python code, I want to automate the retrieval of the tables on this website. On the internet, there are many tutorials on how to obtain data from AJAX requests using the "requests" and "beautifulsoup" libraries. However, in this case, I am unable to proceed because I cannot find the appropriate AJAX request using the developer console.

Can anyone give me some hints on how to start this project right? Do I have to go deeper into the JavaScripts of the website?

Kind Regards

I checked for the Fetch/XHR requests in the developer console in my Chrome browser, but did not find the appropriate request.

I found a document request called ajax/, but I dont know, if it contains useful information.

The following code returns <Response [404]>

```
import requests
url = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/kylian-mbappe/verletzungen/spieler/342229/"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
```

Comment: There are explicit urls to pages that contain the data in source html tables. You don't need to process js to get them.

Comment: For example: `view-source:https://www.transfermarkt.com/kylian-mbappe/verletzungen/spieler/342229/page/2view-source:https://www.transfermarkt.com/kylian-mbappe/verletzungen/spieler/342229/page/2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the necessary headers to avoid blocking. Copy the request as cURL from the browser's network tab.
The below code works fine and returning the proper response.

```py
import requests
headers = {
        'authority': 'www.transfermarkt.de',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.de/kylian-mbappe/verletzungen/spieler/342229/', headers=headers)
print(response)
```

There is another request is going in the back-end for the pagination.

2nd page URL: https://www.transfermarkt.de/kylian-mbappe/verletzungen/spieler/342229/page/2?ajax=yw1